# columns and rows highlight in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I'm new at programming in general but i'm starting to move my first steps into VBA world.

I've been asked to create a macro to highlight the selected cell (also considering the reference column and row) and I managed to put together some pieces of code found online like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'for removing any existing color from the entire sheet

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    a = ActiveCell.Row
    b = ActiveCell.Column

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(a).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(b).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, b).Select

    If (a = 1 And b = a) Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Sub
```

Anyway there are some errors:

1. i'd like to deselect the highlight clicking again on the same cells instead of click on A1 cell.
2. when this macro in enabled it's hard to select columns (need to double click on the column when it's
   just one but have problems when i have to delete a pivot table and consequently more columns at the
   same time).
3. MOST IMPORTANT, it conflicts with other macros.

Can you help me to obtain a clean macro that worked without problems? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code wouldn't be able to deselect the highlighting by clicking in the same cell because that wouldn't trigger the `SelectionChange` event. Your workaround can be to either  program a different macro tied to a different event to turn off highlighting (for example, the double click event). I feel like that would just cause more problems than it's worth. You're likely better off creating a macro to turn off highlighting, and assign it a keyboard shortcut.
2. The problem here is that your current code explicitly tells the application to select the active cell (unnecessarily). So it will deselect the entire column and instead select the cell. Just remove the following line from your code:

   `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, b).Select`
3. You'd need to share more details about the types of conflicts if you'd need more specific help.